# Android Listview on MultipleModal mode doesn't change first selected item

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, multi-select

I have a listview with multiselection mode, it implements in this way :

```
_list.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.MultipleModal;
_list.SetMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultipleModeCallBack(_baseActivity, view, _list, Vm));
```

In `MultipleModeCallBack` I'm trying to change items in listview(for example, change image on another image or hide some views), but when ActionMode create at first time, nothing changes, but when I select new item all works fine. Here code of `MultipleModeCallBack` :

```
    public MultipleModeCallBack(BaseActivity activity, View view, ListView listview, StorageListViewModel vm)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        _view = view;
        _listView = listview;
        _vm = vm;
        _multiButton = _view.FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.MultipleSelectionActionButton);
        _multiButton.Click += ToggleButtonClick;
        _plusButton = _view.FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.PlusButton);

        if (selectedNodes == null)
            selectedNodes = new List<StorageItemViewModel>();
    }

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        _mode = mode;

        for (var i = 0; i < _listView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var view = _listView.GetChildAt(i);
            var holder = (FilesPageFragment.FileStorageItemHolder)view.Tag;
            holder.Button.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        _plusButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        _multiButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        return true;
    }
    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        _plusButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        _multiButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

        for (var i = 0; i < _listView.Adapter.Count; i++)
        {
            var view = _listView.GetChildAt(i);
            var holder = (FilesPageFragment.FileStorageItemHolder)view.Tag;
            DisplayItems(holder, false, i);
            holder.Button.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        selectedNodes.Clear();
    }

    private void DisplayItems(FilesPageFragment.FileStorageItemHolder holder, bool @checked, int position)
    {
        if (@checked)
        {
            holder.Icon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_check_white_24dp);
            holder.Icon.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.Icon.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.multiple_check);
            holder.Icon.SetColorFilter(Graphics.Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.Icon.SetImageResource(Android.App.Utility.AndroidResource.GetIconChar(_vm.StorageList[position].Type));
            holder.Icon.Background = null;
            holder.Icon.SetColorFilter(new Color(Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.GetColor(_activity.BaseContext, Resource.Color.accent)), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
    }

    public void OnItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, bool @checked)
    {
        IsDownloadEnable = true;
        var positions = _listView.CheckedItemPositions;
        if (positions != null)
        {
            var view = _listView.GetChildAt(position);
            DisplayItems((FilesPageFragment.FileStorageItemHolder)view.Tag, @checked, position);

            var length = positions.Size();
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (positions.Get(positions.KeyAt(i)))
                {
                    if (!selectedNodes.Any(item => item.UniqueId == _vm.StorageList[positions.KeyAt(i)].UniqueId))
                        selectedNodes.Add(_vm.StorageList[positions.KeyAt(i)]);
                    if (_vm.StorageList[positions.KeyAt(i)].IsDirectory)
                        IsDownloadEnable = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedNodes.Remove(_vm.StorageList[positions.KeyAt(i)]);
                }
            }
        }
        mode.Title = $"{selectedNodes.Count} items selected";

    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?